# Textbox focus is not working when AjaxControlToolkit TabContainer is used in the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, load, focus, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an asp web page with a text box and I want to set focus on it on load event in code behind in this way:

```
Protected Shadows Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      Page.SetFocus(Me.txtPassword)
      'txtPassword.Focus()

End Sub
```

Both methods are working unless I add a tabcontainer to my page. Below is my web page:

in the header I am registering the AjaxControlToolkit in this way:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Then in my page I have the text box and the tab container:

```
<table style="width: 100%" id="tblnssf" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" runat="server">
   <tr>
       <td style="width: 97px; height: 40px">
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Width="85px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<cc1:TabContainer  ID="TabContainer1" runat="server"  Width="100%">
   <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Header 1">
      <HeaderTemplate>  Header 1 </HeaderTemplate>
      <ContentTemplate> test 1 </ContentTemplate>
   </cc1:TabPanel>

   <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="Header 2">
      <HeaderTemplate>Header 2</HeaderTemplate>
      <ContentTemplate>test 2</ContentTemplate>
   </cc1:TabPanel>
</cc1:TabContainer>
```

When I remove the tab container, both focus methods work properly... And If I add a button and handle its click event from the server side, also focus is working even with the presence of the tab container...  It seems this issue is fired only on load event handled from code behind (server side)
This is really weird and I don't know how to solve it. I really need to set focus onload event from server side not from client side because I am adding some conditions ...  Any helps?